# How to make div box with title text / body text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remake a div box with a title and body text.

What I have: https://i.gyazo.com/23ef74d26988db7ff1a522948f8e66d2.png

What I want: https://i.gyazo.com/0fe544adefe229367b3b8377bf5ad9fa.png

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="everything">
            <div class="header">
                Title
            </div>
            <div class="mainbody">
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, cum explicabo repudiandae sunt et illo alias quasi dolores mollitia corrupti adipisci! Tempora maiores pariatur velit. Dolorum dolores consequatur eveniet perferendis?</p>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, cum explicabo repudiandae sunt et illo alias quasi dolores mollitia corrupti adipisci! Tempora maiores pariatur velit. Dolorum dolores consequatur eveniet perferendis?</p>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, cum explicabo repudiandae sunt et illo alias quasi dolores mollitia corrupti adipisci! Tempora maiores pariatur velit. Dolorum dolores consequatur eveniet perferendis?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
.everything {
    width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.mainbody {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: dimgray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the "title" in your html. The problem is with CSS. Include padding in .mainbody not in .everything. This will work.

```
.everything {
width: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto;
background-color: darkslategrey;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: white;
border-radius: 7px;
border: 1px solid black;}

.mainbody {
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 30%;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0;}
```

[image]